# How does python company the series object that is passed as filter to dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, filtering, series

This must be a obvious one for many.
But I am trying to understand how python matches a filter that is a series object passed to filter in dataframe. For eg:

df is a dataframe

```
mask = df[column1].str.isdigit() == False** ## mask is a series object with boolean values
```

when I do the below, are the indexes of the series (mask) matched with indexes of dataframe df?
if `mask` were another dataframe object and I did the below, then I know it matches the indexes.

```
df[mask]
```

Just trying to clarify my concepts.

Comment: You're using Pandas, right? Please [edit] and add the tag for it.